# how to sort an array by dates in a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, momentjs

I have an array of objects being returned from a REST API. Each of these objects contains it's own array too, like this:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Name 1",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "klqo1gnh",
          "name": "Item 1",
          "date": "2019-05-12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Name 2",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "klqo2fho",
          "name": "Item 1",
          "date": "2021-05-05"
        },
        {
          "id": "klro8wip",
          "name": "Item 2",
          "date": "2012-05-05"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I then map over the data, and return it, like this (this is a very stripped down example):

```
{content.map((item) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {item.name}
            {item.date}
            {item.id}
        </div>
    );
})}
```

Much like you'd expect. What I need to do, however, is sort this by date, preferably using `Moment.js`, finding the item in the array that contains the earliest date, and then displaying that item first. For example, item `"id": 2` contains the date `2012-05-05`, and since that's the earliest date in the data, I need that item to be first. I'm really lost here, Moment's documentation isn't super clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), something like: 
`sortContent: (items) => {  return content.sort((a, b) =>   (a.item.date > b.item.date) - (b.item.date > a.item.date)  ); }`

Comment: And with momentjs use it like so: `moment(a.item.date).isAfter(moment(b.item.date))` or `isBefore()` or `isSame()`.

Comment: @k-wasilewski Better option is just [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) it'll return a timestamp, which is then easily sortable (bigger = later)

Comment: I'm aware, but he precisely asked about moment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function which takes an array of `items` as a parameter and returns a new array sorted by date, using Moment.js, could be something like this:

```
function sortByDate(items: any[]) {
    return items.sort((first, second) => {
        if (moment(first.data.date).isSame(second.data.date)) {
            return -1; // If they have the same date, return the first item
        } else if (moment(first.data.date).isBefore(second.data.date)) {
            return -1; // If the first date is earlier, return the first item
        } else {
            return 1; // The second date is earlier, so it goes first;
        }
    })
}
```

Then you can use this function before mapping `content`

Comment: Probably don't need to use Moment just for sorting, as the timespamp returned by `Date.parse('str')` will always be sortable

Comment: I agree, if it's just for sorting I personally prefer to use the `.parse()` method like you said instead of moment

Comment: Just running the code now, and unfortunently it doesn't work, as `data` is an array, so I guess OP wants the actual data array sorted, as well as the `content` array of objects

Answer (score -1):

Did you ever use the sort method of the JavaScript array?

`array.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)`

If `a.value - b.value` is bigger than 0, then b is former item than a.

Comment: Welcome @Viktor P. Could you give OP an example of this working, as just this alone should be a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about true. It should be compared with zero not being true or false.

Comment: No problem :) I mean, maybe show a working code example, using OPs data. Your suggestion is good, but on it's own it won't work for OPs nested data structure. Since it's not an answer, it should probably just be a comment